# How to link to the application installation screen in Software Center?

Tags: windows-10, sccm

How do I link to the Application Details screen in Software Center for an application? I support a couple corporate appications we have in Software Center and I want to be able to get my users to that screen with a single click of a link.

I'm not trying to install the application automatically, I just want the users to get to this screen so they can click Install themselves.

This is the screen:
[image: The screen in Software Center that I want to link to.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with (I believe) current branch 1706 a *Share* button was added to the application page of individual applications in Software Center. It can be found in the upper right of the window. I did not see it called out in the release notes but it is described here:

[SCCM 1706 – Share an application from Software Center](https://nhogarth.net/2017/07/31/sccm-1706-share-an-application-from-software-center/)